# What / where is "builtin-copy" that Xcode is using?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

If I look at the details from a build of an iOS app, in the copy resources phase, I see Xcode claim to be using something called "builtin-copy":

```
CpResource /svn/MyProject/MyResources/myLog.json /Users/benjamin.flynn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gocyhvchxrohmbbgmgbzzxtztbku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/myLog.json
cd "/svn/MyProject/MyApp"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode-5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-5.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /svn/MyProject/MyResources/myLog.json /Users/benjamin.flynn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gocyhvchxrohmbbgmgbzzxtztbku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app
```

Is `builtin-copy` something internal to Xcode? I ask because if I set my path to what Xcode is setting it to, I do not have a builtin-copy command available. It seems handy. I'm looking to copy my own resource in a shell script so I was looking at the Xcode phase for reference.

Comment: The name suggest that "builtin-copy" is built into the Xcode application itself, and therefore not available as a separate command line tool.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I was reading "builtin" as referring to some shell, but your suggestion seems very plausible.

Comment: FWIW, seems like it does the same thing as `rsync -r --exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS --exclude .svn --exclude .git --exclude .hg --copy-links /svn/MyProject/MyResources/myLog.json /Users/benjamin.flynn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gocyhvchxrohmbbgmgbzzxtztbku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app`

Comment: that would work as an answer, @BenFlynn

Answer (score 3):

Moving my comment to an answer. Seems like CpResource does the same thing as:

```
rsync -r --exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS --exclude .svn --exclude .git --exclude .hg --copy-links /svn/MyProject/MyResources/myLog.json /Users/benjamin.flynn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gocyhvchxrohmbbg‌​mgbzzxtztbku/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app
```

Comment: I don't get how this is answer, if Rsync definitely doesn't have options like `-bitcode-strip` or `-strip-debug-symbols`.

Comment: I undid the acceptance of this answer -- those are good points! The above is only _some_ of what CpResource is doing. Perhaps someone else has a more complete answer.

Comment: I think for the bitcode parameters they internally call `bitcode_strip` to add/remove the bitcode flag.